# A (comprehensive) URI parser for Python

Tags: python, parsing, url

For a code challenge, I'm trying to write a comprehensive URI parser in Python that handles both URIs with `authority` paths (ex: URLs such as `http://user:login@site.com/page?key=value#fragment`) and other URI schemes (ex: `mailto:mail@domain.com?subject=Blah`).

Here's my current code:

```
import json
import re
class Uri(object):
    """ Utility class to handle URIs """


    ESCAPE_CODES = {' ' : '%20', '<' : '%3C', '>' : '%3E', '#' : '%23', '%' : '%25', '{' : '%7B',
                    '}' : '%7D', '|' : '%7C', '\\' : '%5C', '^' : '%5E', '~' : '%7E', '[' : '%5B',
                    ']' : '%5D', '`' : '%60', ';' : '%3B', '/' : '%2F', '?' : '%3F', ':' : '%3A',
                    '@' : '%40', '=' : '%3D', '&' : '%26', '$' : '%24'}
    @staticmethod
    def encode(string):
        """ "Percent-encodes" the given string """
        return ''.join(c if not c in Uri.ESCAPE_CODES else Uri.ESCAPE_CODES[c] for c in string)

    # We could parse (most of) the URI using this regex given on the RFC 3986:
    # http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#appendix-B
    # We won't do it though because it spoils all the fun! \o/
    # We're only going to use it detect broken URIs
    URI_REGEX = "^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?"

    def __init__(self, uri):
        """ Parses the given URI """

        uri = uri.strip()

        if not re.match(Uri.URI_REGEX, uri):
            raise ValueError("The given URI isn't valid")

        # URI scheme is case-insensitive
        self.scheme = uri.split(':')[0].lower()

        self.path = uri[len(self.scheme) + 1:]

        # URI fragments
        self.fragment = None
        if '#' in self.path:
            self.path, self.fragment = self.path.split('#')

        # Query parameters (for instance: http://mysite.com/page?key=value&other_key=value2)
        self.parameters = dict()
        if '?' in self.path:
            separator = '&' if '&' in self.path else ';'
            query_params = self.path.split('?')[-1].split(separator)
            query_params = map(lambda p : p.split('='), query_params)
            self.parameters = {key : value for key, value in query_params}
            self.path = self.path.split('?')[0]


        # For URIs that have a path starting with '//', we try to fetch additional info:
        self.authority = None
        if self.path.startswith('//'):
            self.path = self.path.lstrip('//')
            uri_tokens = self.path.split('/')

            self.authority = uri_tokens[0]
            self.hostname = self.authority
            self.path = self.path[len(self.authority):]

            # Fetching authentication data. For instance: "http://login:password@site.com"
            self.authenticated = '@' in self.authority
            if self.authenticated:
                self.user_information, self.hostname = self.authority.split('@', 1)

            # Fetching port
            self.port = None
            if ':' in self.hostname:
                self.hostname, self.port = self.hostname.split(':')
                self.port = int(self.port)

            # Hostnames are case-insensitive
            self.hostname = self.hostname.lower()


    def serialize_parameters(self):
        """ Returns a serialied representation of the query parameters. """
        return '&'.join('{}={}'.format(key, value) for key, value in sorted(self.parameters.iteritems()))


    def __str__(self):
        """ Outputs the URI as a string """
        uri = '{}:'.format(Uri.encode(self.scheme))

        if self.authority:
            uri += '//'
            if self.authenticated:
                uri += Uri.encode(self.user_information) + '@'
            uri += self.hostname
            if self.port:
                uri += ':{}'.format(self.port)

        uri += self.path
        if self.parameters:
            uri += '?' + self.serialize_parameters()
        if self.fragment:
            uri += '#' + Uri.encode(self.fragment)
        return uri

    def json(self):
        """ JSON serialization of the URI object """
        return json.dumps(self.__dict__, sort_keys=True, indent=2)

    def summary(self):
        """ Summary of the URI object. Mostly for debug. """
        uri_repr = '{}\n'.format(self)
        uri_repr += '\n'
        uri_repr += "* Schema name: '{}'\n".format(self.scheme)

        if self.authority:
            uri_repr += "* Authority path: '{}'\n".format(self.authority)

            uri_repr += "  . Hostname: '{}'\n".format(self.hostname)
            if self.authenticated:
                uri_repr += "  . User information = '{}'\n".format(self.user_information)
            if self.port:
                uri_repr += "  . Port = '{}'\n".format(self.port)

        uri_repr += "* Path: '{}'\n".format(self.path)
        if self.parameters:
            uri_repr += "* Query parameters: '{}'\n".format(self.parameters)
        if self.fragment:
            uri_repr += "* Fragment: '{}'\n".format(self.fragment)
        return uri_repr
```

Also [hosted on github](https://github.com/halflings/uriparser).

All feedback, including failure to respect PEP8 or existence of more "pythonic" methods, is welcome!

Comment: There is no better place to look at than the python standard library:
http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/urlparse.py

Comment: It might seem arrogant, but I don't think urlparse's implementation isn't the most elegant one. (other Python Standard Libraries are also horrible, like the ones handling ZIP and TAR files)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You referenced [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), but I don't think you've tried to follow it.

In your constructor, you immediately lower-case everything.  That is obviously wrong.   [RFC 3986 Sec. 6.2.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-6.2.2.1) says that only the scheme and host portions of URIs are case-insensitive.

You have an `escape()` function, but oddly no `unescape()` function, which I expect would be needed for parsing URIs.  Please be aware when implementing `unescape()` that query strings have special unescaping rules.  The RFC uses the term "percent-encoding", so perhaps you should call it "encode" rather than "escape".

Your `escape()` function only encodes specific characters, which is dangerous, considering that more characters exist that require encoding than that can be passed through.

Be careful when calling `split()` where you expect at most one separator.  You should use `split(':', 1)`, `split('@', 1)` and `split('#', 1)` instead.

Better yet, don't try to split at all.  Instead, consistently use regular expression capturing for identifying *all* parts of the URI.  You should be able to make one huge regular expression.  All complex regular expressions, including the one you are using now, should have embedded [comments](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE).

Comment: I quickly skimmed over RFC 3986 and have, as you proved it, missed many things. I'm gonna try to fix those asap!

I tried to avoid using one big pile of regex (event commented) because I think the goal of this programming exercise was to parse string in various ways and show a good coding style. Using one big regex wouldn't be relevant IMHO.

Comment: Regarding the "percent-encoding", from what I've understood only reserved characters must be percented-encoded in the URI. And I think I already got all of those covered.

Comment: [Sec 2.1](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.1): "A percent-encoding mechanism is used to represent a data octet in a component when that octet's corresponding character is outside the allowed set or is being used as a delimiter of, or within, the component." The reserved set contains a list of common delimiters. There are also plenty of characters outside the allowed set. [Appendix A](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#appendix-A) suggests that anything outside the nonreserved set should be percent-encoded if it's not being used for a syntactically significant role in the URL.

Comment: OK! Forgot about non ASCII letters and other exotic characters.